# How to save data in two NSMutableArray into a single entity using magical record

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

I'm fetching `code` & `desc` from web by calling an API. Then loading it into `tableView` and based on multiple selection I'm saving the selected values into two arrays i.e. `selectedCode` and `selectedCodeDesc`. My Entity is:

[image]

So I want to `[[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] MR_saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error){` but don't know how. I know this much:

```
- (IBAction)confirmPressed:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Selected Are: %@ - %@",selectedDX,selectedDesc);
    for (NSString *code in selectedDX) {
        if (!_dxToAddEdit) {
            self.dxToAddEdit = [MainCode MR_createEntity];
        }

        [self.dxToAddEdit setCode:code];
        [self.dxToAddEdit setCodeDescription:@""]; //what to give here
        [self.dxToAddEdit setSuperBill:_forSuperBill];
    }
    //after this I'm calling the saveToPersistent
```

So what to give at setCodeDescription?

Comment: Are you working with coredata ?

Comment: yes but I'm using MagicalRecords. I've just updated my question see the code.

Comment: MainCode is entity ?

Comment: [self.dxToAddEdit setCodeDescription:@"Hello description pass as string what ever you want "];

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya yes MainCode is entity and I can't set @"some string" as I've codeDescription in a codeDesc array and code name in code array.

Comment: if you need then i give you one simple project that working with core data

Comment: I already have good tutorial like http://myioslearning.blogspot.com/2016/10/relationships-in-coredata-using-magical.html and http://myioslearning.blogspot.com/2016/09/step-by-step-core-data-with.html I just want to know how to save data from two different arrays into on entity

Comment: in entity you just pass value its depands on you what value you pass for particular attribute .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly and based on your description and example of code you can do the following:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *defaultContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext];
// Sorry, I renamed selectedCode to selectedCodes and selectedCodeDesc to selectedCodeDescriptions for readability.
// Not sure whether selectedDX is actually selectedCodes.
for (NSInteger i=0; i<selectedCodes.count; ++i) {
    NSString *code = selectedCodes[i];
    NSString *description = selectedCodeDescriptions[i];
    Diagnoses *newDiagnose = [Diagnoses MR_createEntityInContext:defaultContext];

    newDiagnose.code = code;
    newDiagnose.codeDescription = description;
    newDiagnose.superBill = _forSuperBill;
}

[defaultContext MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
```

Actually, I would not save the response into two separated arrays. Because of:

- Your code becomes difficult to read
- Imagine that the model will change and instead of two properties it will contain 4. You will have to create additional arrays.

I would recommend you to parse the response directly into the managed objects. Of course, you may not save them into persistent storage just populate your table view.
I highly recommend you to read [these tutorials about Core Data](https://code.tutsplus.com/series/core-data-from-scratch--cms-653). It will give you insight how to work with Magical Record library. Although, the library simplifies a lot of work it would be better to know what is under the hood ;]

Comment: Your the savior of the day :D I'm new to core data and yes I know a lot of things I'm doing are considered as bad approaches but that's how you learn. I'll keep your suggestion in mind for future as right now everything is working fine and I don't want to mess it up :P